# STM32 Nucelo board's LD1 LED color and ST-LINK Utility

Tags: stm32, nucleo

When I program my STM32 Nucleo board([STM3232 F302R8](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f302r8.html#overview)) through PC's USB, the LD1 LED of the board is always red after I upload the code by using ST-LINK Utility.
And color remains red even though I disconnect from ST-LINK Utility or even after hardware reset.

But when I restart computer LD1 becomes green. How can I obtain green without restarting it. I use ST-LINK of the board and UART2 interrupt in a way that when I send a character through USB a function starts running.

I read that in general, the LD1 LED turning green usually indicates that the board is properly powered and ready for communication. Is there a way to make LD1 green without restarting the PC? I want to successfully communicate through USB ST-Link which color better for LD1?

Comment: Have you read the board manual about LD1 states?

Comment: Yes I read but maybe interpret wrong section 6.4: https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf It says "Green LED On: after a successful target communication initialization" But I only have the LD1 green after I restart the PC otherwise always red. And when its red I sometimes have issues like board doesnt receive uart interrupt but that doesn't happen when green.

Comment: Did the board work fine the first time you power it up?

Comment: @Rodo Yes it worked fine.

Comment: Its strange that I couldnt find a way to make LD1 green besides restarting the PC which powers the Nucleo through USB.

Comment: Did u try to press the reset button on the board after you programmed it? Mine needs that sometimes.

Comment: Reset button does not affect the ST-Link MCU, other that makes the ST-Link MCU to lose communication with the target MCU. The question is, why would the LED of the ST-Link status matter on a dev board? Remove it or change green/red between each other.

Comment: @Rodo As Justme says it doesnt affect because after such HW reset the LD1 finally becomes red again. There is so far no way to make it green inless I restart the computer. Even I remove and plug in USB cable it still gets back to red. Only PC restart makes it green and if I upload code by the ST-LINK Utility it end up as constant red. (of course Im not mentioning blinking state during uploads)

Comment: Do any of you have a similar board? Does it behave same way?

Comment: I have a Nucleo-H745. Is this the first program you are trying? Are u using the stm32cubeIDE? if so, did u started the project from the board template in stm32cubeIDE?

Comment: Yes I use stm32cubeIDE to program but I use  ST-LINK Utility to connect to in board ST-LINK and upload the code((bin/hex file) that way. After that LD1 becomes red. In your case after you upload the code what color does the LD1 settle?

Comment: That utility has been replaced: https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link004.html

Comment: You can program the board from within the cubeIDE. If this is your first program I suggest you try something simpler like blinking the user LED on your board first.

Comment: @Rodo I get the same results with cubeIDE so its not about the utility.

Comment: Did u make a simple blink LED project? Can u zip it and add it (use edit) to your question?

Comment: It is not about the type of project its always how I described. Has nothing to do about the code.